# Make meteor refresh stylesheet only

Tags: stylesheet, meteor

I've noticed that when working on a meteor application it will auto refresh the entire page when any stylesheets have changed. Is there a way to make it only refresh the stylesheet assets similar to how LiveReload works?

Also note that I'm using `stylus` for my stylesheets. Is that what's causing the full reload?

Answer (score 0):

No, out-of-the-box Meteor will reload the entire app when it detects a file change of any type (whether html, css, or js). It doesn't matter if you're using `stylus` or not.

I imagine future iterations may take a page of out `LiveReload` for images and css files (so changing them does not cause a refresh), but for the time being the whole site will reload. In fact, this would probably be a fantastic pull request.

Answer (score 0):

The current workaround I found is to use the "regular way" of adding css files:

1. Put your file myCss.css into the public folder "/public/myCss.css" so that it is not compiled by meteor
2. Add the following line to your html file:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myCss.css" />
   ```
3. Use a live editor such as Espresso or CSSEdit to change the myCss.css file.

Note that once you save the file, meteor will reload anyway. But in the following case:
- You are running meteor in production mode
- Your .css file is not in any folder contained into the meteor project (like you serve the .css file from somewhere else my yourself)
- Your file or folder is starting with a dot "." or ending with tilde "~", in this case, meteor will not reload those files if they did changed. Note that I never have been able to make this work with the ending tilde, moreover working with invisible files (starting with ".") is not very convenient. [See here for ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823783/how-to-disable-hot-code-push-in-meteor-js-in-development)