# How to disable Hot Code Push in Meteor JS in Development?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using Tincr (http://tin.cr/) to take advantage of Chrome's code hot-swapping functionality. However, now I need to disable Meteor's refreshing of the page each time I save a file since the code is already update in the browser's runtime environment thanks to chrome hot-swapping.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i found the answer. add a '~' at the end of files or folders you don't want causing reloads.